# How to access child prop ref with vue 3 and Element Plus ui lib

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, element-plus

I have a ref on a dropdown component called 'dropdown'

when an item is selected, I want to get the selected label(I can get the value, but its different than the label)

when I do dropdown.value I get an object where I can see the key with its value I want within it, which is 'selectedLabel'

if I do dropdown.value.selectedLabel I get blank and dropdown.value.selectedLabel.value is undefined.

https://codesandbox.io/s/element-plus-demo-forked-2n982?file=/src/App.vue

Please check image to see template and the logs I get back:
[image]

```html
<template>
  <div class="dropdown-component">
    <div class="label">{{name}}</div>
    <div class="select-container">
      <el-select
        ref="dropdown"
        v-model="selectedValue"
        filterable
        @change="$emit('OPTION_SELECTED', selectedOptionData())"
        :placeholder="placeholderText"
      >
        <el-option
          v-for="(item,index) in options"
          :key="index"
          :label="getLabel(item)"
          :value="getValue(item)"
        >
        </el-option>
      </el-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, defineComponent, watchEffect, computed } from 'vue'
import { getAPIObjFor } from '@/lib/ymm/YMMApi'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    labelKey: String,
    valueKey: { type: String, default: '' },
    name: String,
    next: String,
    groupState: Object
  },

  emits: ['OPTION_SELECTED'],

  setup (props) {
    console.log('Initing Dropdown-', props.name)

    const options = ref([])
    const selectedValue = ref('')
    const activeQueryParam = ref('')
    const dropdown = ref(null)
    const apiQueryObj = getAPIObjFor(props.name)

    const getOptionData = async ({ apiQuery, apiRequest }) => {
      // keep log
      console.log('%c' + props.name + ' query:', 'color:orange', apiQuery)
      activeQueryParam.value = apiQuery
      options.value = await apiRequest(apiQuery)
    }

    const getLabel = (_item) => {
      return _item[props.labelKey]
    }

    const getValue = (_item) => {
      const valueKey = props.valueKey === '' ? props.labelKey : props.valueKey
      return { value: _item[valueKey], label: getLabel(_item), x: 'x' }
    }

    const selectedOptionData = () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line dot-notation
      // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-ref-as-operand
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('selected dropdown', dropdown.value, dropdown.value.clearIcon, dropdown.value.selectedLabel)
      const { name } = props
      const { value, label } = selectedValue.value
      const selectedData = {
        [`${name}`]: {
          value,
          label,
          next: props.next
        }
      }
      return selectedData
    }

    const placeholderText = computed(() => {
      return `Select a ${props.name}`
    })

    watchEffect(() => {
      const query = apiQueryObj(props.groupState)
      if (query && query.apiQuery !== activeQueryParam.value) {
        selectedValue.value = ''
        getOptionData(query)
      }
    })

    return { options, getValue, getLabel, selectedValue, selectedOptionData, placeholderText, dropdown }
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.dropdown-component {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .select-container {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .el-select {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

</style>
```

Comment: See how to properly create a [mcve]. Your code snippet does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `el-select`'s `selected` property instead of `selectedLabel`, which always seems to be blank for some reason.

The `selected` property contains an array of selected options (each containing a `currentLabel` property), where the last array element is the most recently selected. However, the `selected` property is updated after the `change` event, so you have to await the next tick before accessing it.

```js
import { nextTick } from 'vue'
//...

const selectedOptionData = async () => {
  await nextTick()
  const selected = dropdown.value.selected.at(-1).currentLabel
  console.log('selectedLabel', selected)
  //...
}
```

Also your `@change` event handler would have to be modified to be async for this to work:

```html
<el-select @change="onChange">
```

```js
export default {
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const onChange = async () => {
      emit('OPTION_SELECTED', await selectedOptionData())
    }

    return { onChange }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-el-select-tag-label-on-change-mtz9b?file=/src/App.vue:530-707)

Just be aware that the `change`-event also occurs when a tag is removed.

Comment: I know I can get the value, then use the options array to find the label. The solution I implemented was to pass an object as a value that contains {value,label} so when I read the value I can do value.label or value.value. which i feel is kinda dumb, I wanted to grab via dropdown.value.selectedLabel which seems cleaner cus now my return value needs to be parsed to get actual value lol.

Comment: Use `dropdown.value.selected.at(-1).currentLabel` to get the selected item's label (see updated answer). FWIW, your solution of passing an object as a value is cleaner to me than using the template ref.

Comment: ah man I had a feeling it was related to a tick issue. I just was overly confident that what I saw in dropdown.value was something I could immediately select :(  Thanks alot for the help! Yeah I agree, for sure ill keep my value as an object vs updating to async/next tick